# Simple "find and replace" Python script for editing a csv is giving errors

Tags: python, csv

A very simple find and replace script for cleaning up a CSV file. This worked before but now I am getting several odd errors.

It takes in a csv (Out.csv), finds a string `find_str` and replaces it with `replace_str`.

Running: `python3 cleanup.ph -i Out.csv` gives the errors pasted below.

**The script:**

```
import re

# open your csv and read as a text string
with open('Out.csv', 'r') as f:
    my_csv_text = f.read()

find_str = 'first published'
replace_str = ' '

# substitute
new_csv_str = re.sub(find_str, replace_str, my_csv_text)

# open new file and save
new_csv_path = './my_new_csv.csv' # or whatever path and name you want
with open(new_csv_path, 'w') as f:
    f.write(new_csv_str)
```

**The Errors:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cleanup.py", line 11, in <module>
    new_csv_str = re.sub(find_str, replace_str, my_csv_text)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 192, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 286, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/sre_compile.py", line 764, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py", line 924, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py", line 420, in _parse_sub
    not nested and not items))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py", line 813, in _parse
    source.tell() - start)
re.error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 1
```

Comment: Is there a reason you just don't do `new_csv_str = my_csv_text.replace(find_str, replace_str)`? And don't use regex at all?

Comment: That makes no sense unless the `find_str` in your actual code is different from what you posted here.

Comment: Yeah, show us the actual value of `find_str` that you got this error with please.

Comment: Your [mre] should include a few lines of the csv text that will cause the error.

Comment: What you are getting in print(my_csv_text), maybe you are getting wrong output here.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I was useing this find_str = find_str = '(first published'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was uing a ( in the find_str. For some reason that made it not work. thhank you guys!!!

Comment: This really isn't an answer. You should answer showing the final solution and maybe explaining why it solved the problem and what was wrong with the original - be verbose.